# Ubuntu 20.04 not scaled properly for 1366x768 display

Tags: display, display-resolution, vmware, scaling

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my 1366×768 resolution display and noticed that the screen was conjusted. The window template was also larger. It looks like it was not optimized for my display.

Also while using some applications like VMware I can't click on the **OK** Button because the whole VMware window was not being displayed (the bottom part of VMware was not visible). Please help.

[image: link for desktop image]

**Please Note:** Windows 10 display was working perfectly for my resolution.

Comment: Is this a laptop or external?  Would go to system settings, screen display and see what your choices are.

Comment: This is a laptop. The choices are 1366x768, 1360x768, 1280x720, 1024x768, 960x720, 928x696, 896x696, 1024x576, 960x600, 960x540, 800x600.

Comment: Does choosing the 1366x768 option work to fix or are you already on it.?  Also check other settings.

Comment: i am already on the max resolution on my laptop which is 1366x768. The resolution works fine with windows.

Comment: Your screen shot does not look that bad.  Terminal is long to me, but you probably have your terminals setting like that.  does the applications you are having problem with cover full screen or just part of screen and are too low?  Their screen size settings might need adjusting.  Most applications have their own settings for screen size and placement, most of defaults do a decent job.

Comment: while using Vmware workstation i can't see the bottom portion of the windows

Comment: Is Vmware going right to top screen(below top panel)?  If not can usually move it up some.  Might also need to adjust Vmware settings for size/placement onscreen.  Something with Vmware on Ubuntu might just be a bit off.  Windows and Ubuntu do not share settings, like having two separate computers.

Comment: yes it is going just below the top panel. it won't go up any further.

Comment: I found the fix here, I'm posting this answer here if that is still happening to someone.
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxcvt/-/merge_requests/9